# Media Source Extensions append after reload page

Tags: javascript, media-source

I am writing a webinar platform and using MediaRecorder on the presenter’s speaker client and Media Source Extensions on the listener client. The initial byte segment contains all the information about the video, and the subsequent ones contain only the timestamp (https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/#init-segment). I ensured that the video was sent without failures from the first client to the second client. But when I refresh the page on the listener's client, the media stream immediately stops, because no start segment. Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to segment the stream yourself.

If you're using WebM, just keep everything up to the start of the first [Cluster](https://www.matroska.org/technical/diagram/index.html) and treat this as the initialization segment.  Then, you can pick up anywhere in the stream at the beginning of a cluster that has a keyframe.

Unfortunately for you, you don't get to tell the browser where to insert keyframes when you're recording with MediaRecorder.  So, you'll either have to determine which clusters have keyframes yourself, or do some server-side transcoding.  The latter was likely required anyway, unless you were planning to serve the same bitrate/encoding to all clients.

Comment: Yes, I use webm. "So, you'll either have to determine which clusters have keyframes yourself" -  should it be done on the client side? Can you provide example please? I use java spring mvc on server side.

Comment: @stim644 I don't know how to do that.  There isn't a flag in the Cluster at the WebM/Mastroska level that says, "this one has a keyframe!", so you need to dig into the codec data itself within the cluster.  You're better off transcoding server-side, and then you can start each cluster with a keyframe.

Comment: Recode on server side to the starting frame is possible, yes?